# Questions with expired bounty

Tags: discussion, specific-question, bounty

In case of questions where the bounty amount expires, I believe the bounty is supposed to be given to the highest voted answer after the bounty was announced, with atleast 2 upvotes.

However, how does it work if no such answer was created?

I am specifically asking w.r.t this question

[Unable to install Windows XP : Blue screen error pops up before "Starting Windows Setup"](https://superuser.com/questions/211582/unable-to-install-windows-xp-blue-screen-error-pops-up-before-starting-windows/213362#213362)

where the bounty was awarded to harrymc whose answer was 1 hour before mine, both have 2 upvotes and both were posted before the bounty.

However, the bounty was awarded to harrymc. whats the reason behind that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, how does it work if no such answer was created?

I believe no bounty is awarded if the bounty conditions do not match.

> where the bounty was awarded to harrymc whose answer was 1 hour before mine, both have 2 upvotes and **both were posted before the bounty.**

That's not quite correct.

The bounty was started on 20th.

[image]

You posted on Nov 21, 08:28, harry posted on Nov 21, 07:46. Community chose harry's because he had posted prior to you. Seems fine to me.

Comment: FAQ says  "If you do not award your bounty within 7 days, the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with at least 2 upvotes will be awarded half the bounty amount."   both our answers were before the bounty started..

Comment: Bounty was started [on 20th](http://superuser.com/posts/211582/revisions). You posted on Nov 21, 08:28, harry posted on 07:46. Community chose harry's because he had posted prior to you. Seems fine to me.

Comment: OK.. Misremembered the date I guess..